# update linq related table

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a User table  like (Id,Name,UserAddresId) and UserAddress table like(Id,AddressOne) with a `FormView Control` and i want to have an update command in it. Here's my form:

```
    <asp:FormView ID="orderInfolst" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="OrderSrc">
    <ItemTemplate>
     Name:
     <asp:Label ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /> 
     User Address One 
     <asp:Label ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserAddresses.AddressOne") %>' />  
 <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="ویرایش" />    
</ItemTemplate>
    <EditTemplate>
     Name:
     <asp:TextBox ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' /> 
     User Address One; 
     <asp:TextBox ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserAddresses.AddressOne") %>' />
 <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server"   CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"  Text="ویرایش شود" />
                          &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="لغو شود" />

    </EditTemplate>
```

and in server I have a handler for ItemUpdated Event like this:

```
if (e.Exception == null)
{
    Resultlbl.Text = "update successfully ";
}
else 
{
    Resultlbl.Text = e.Exception.Message;
}
```

I get the **Update Successfully** message. so Name filed updated but  **AddressOne** in related Table not updated!!! what is wrong here?

Comment: can you provide a full source code.?

Comment: @VishalSuthar yes, but here's all thing i do in my code

Comment: how these two tables are join,is `UserAddresId` in `user table` is the `foreign key` of `primary key` of column `Id` in `UserAddress` table.

Comment: @Rahul hi, naturally UserAddressId is FK in User Table and Id is PK in UserAddresses table

Comment: @Rahul but i have another relation like same relation. is it important?

Comment: @Rahul i delete same relation. but problem not solved. tnx

Comment: can you show me a full code of `ItemUpdated Event` ? did you `submitChanged()` ?

Comment: Does the update command actually run? Is the command correct? Maybe you can show it.

Comment: @zey dear friend it name update correctly without any exception. but my ralaited field (userAddress.AddressOne) Not update!

Comment: @zey a also use a raw aspx page with just this code. but it doesn't work ,doesn't update, related field. i think there is a bug in vs 2012! . you can test it.

Comment: What I know of FormView is that you have to set an update command. Did you read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @GertArnold tnx dear, but i also test it in grid. doesn't work. i will read that, tnx

Comment: @GertArnold yes, update actually run correctly(i get seccessfully updated message) and update my name field but doesn't update Useraddress.addressOne, and ther is no Exception

Comment: @GertArnold , sorry. yes. db was updated

Comment: @GertArnold I asked here , tnx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063447/update-parent-child-table