# update parent child table

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two table, they are parent child.  testtypes(Id,Name), testusers(Id,TypeId,Name)
i want update them in gridview. testusers (name filed) was updated but testTypes(testtype.Name field) doesn't update. 
there is no exception. (i check the e.exception == null variable in GridviewUpdated handler.) 
i'm really confuesd! it's so strange. i think vs 2012 has bug!
here's my  markup and code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ahooratech.WebForm4" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="testtype.Name" HeaderText="mytypid"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Ahooratech.DAL.DataClasses1DataContext" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="testusers">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace Ahooratech
    {
        public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               gv.rowUpdated += handler;
            }
    void gv_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.exception == null) 
        {
         resultlbl.text = "Update seccessfully";// i get this message and name update in db
        }
    }

 }
```

}

and DAL:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="AhooraTechdb")]
    public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {

        private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();



        public DataClasses1DataContext() : 
                base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AhooraTechdbConnectionString1"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public DataClasses1DataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<AdminUser> AdminUsers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<AdminUser>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<WishProduct> WishProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<WishProduct>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Advertisement> Advertisements
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Advertisement>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<aspnet_Application> aspnet_Applications
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<aspnet_Application>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<aspnet_Membership> aspnet_Memberships
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<aspnet_Membership>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<aspnet_SchemaVersion> aspnet_SchemaVersions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<aspnet_SchemaVersion>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<aspnet_User> aspnet_Users
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<aspnet_User>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<BillingType> BillingTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<BillingType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<BoolValue> BoolValues
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<BoolValue>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ContainerItem> ContainerItems
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ContainerItem>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Container> Containers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Container>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Country> Countries
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Country>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DeliveryTimeType> DeliveryTimeTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DeliveryTimeType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DeliveryType> DeliveryTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DeliveryType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DescriptiveValue> DescriptiveValues
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DescriptiveValue>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DiscountCode> DiscountCodes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DiscountCode>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DiscountCodesPrice> DiscountCodesPrices
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DiscountCodesPrice>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DiscountcodesProduct> DiscountcodesProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DiscountcodesProduct>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DiscountCodesUser> DiscountCodesUsers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DiscountCodesUser>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<DiscountType> DiscountTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<DiscountType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<MeasurmentValue> MeasurmentValues
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<MeasurmentValue>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductImage> ProductImages
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductImage>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductOption> ProductOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductOption>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductProductOption> ProductProductOptions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductProductOption>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Product>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductsCat> ProductsCats
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductsCat>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductsDescriptionImage> ProductsDescriptionImages
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductsDescriptionImage>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductsPeripheralProduct> ProductsPeripheralProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductsPeripheralProduct>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductsProperty> ProductsProperties
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductsProperty>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ProductsRelatedProduct> ProductsRelatedProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ProductsRelatedProduct>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Property> Properties
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Property>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<PropertyCat> PropertyCats
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<PropertyCat>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<RetrurnedOrder> RetrurnedOrders
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<RetrurnedOrder>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ReturnCause> ReturnCauses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ReturnCause>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ShippingType> ShippingTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ShippingType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ShortDescriptiveValue> ShortDescriptiveValues
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ShortDescriptiveValue>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<SqlDataType> SqlDataTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<SqlDataType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<State> States
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<State>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<StatesShippingType> StatesShippingTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<StatesShippingType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<StockStateType> StockStateTypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<StockStateType>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<test> tests
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<test>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Unit> Units
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Unit>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<UserRequestProduct> UserRequestProducts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<UserRequestProduct>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<User>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Warranty> Warranties
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Warranty>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<SideBarMenuItem> SideBarMenuItems
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<SideBarMenuItem>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<OrderItem> OrderItems
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<OrderItem>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<UserAddress> UserAddresses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<UserAddress>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Basket> Baskets
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Basket>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ElseCost> ElseCosts
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ElseCost>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<OrderStatuse> OrderStatuses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<OrderStatuse>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ShipmentStatuse> ShipmentStatuses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ShipmentStatuse>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<ConfirmStatuse> ConfirmStatuses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<ConfirmStatuse>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<PaymentStatuse> PaymentStatuses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<PaymentStatuse>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Order> Orders
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Order>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<testtype> testtypes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<testtype>();
            }
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<testuser> testusers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<testuser>();
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.FetchProperties")]
        public ISingleResult<FetchPropertiesResult> FetchProperties([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ProductId", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> productId)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), productId);
            return ((ISingleResult<FetchPropertiesResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
    }
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.testtypes")]
    public partial class testtype : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private int _Id;

        private string _Name;

        private EntitySet<testuser> _testusers;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
    partial void OnIdChanged();
    partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();
    #endregion

        public testtype()
        {
            this._testusers = new EntitySet<testuser>(new Action<testuser>(this.attach_testusers), new Action<testuser>(this.detach_testusers));
            OnCreated();
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Id != value))
                {
                    this.OnIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Id = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                    this.OnIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Name != value))
                {
                    this.OnNameChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Name = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Name");
                    this.OnNameChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="testtype_testuser", Storage="_testusers", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="TypeId")]
        public EntitySet<testuser> testusers
        {
            get
            {
                return this._testusers;
            }
            set
            {
                this._testusers.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void attach_testusers(testuser entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.testtype = this;
        }

        private void detach_testusers(testuser entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.testtype = null;
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.testusers")]
    public partial class testuser : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private int _Id;

        private string _Name;

        private System.Nullable<int> _TypeId;

        private EntityRef<testtype> _testtype;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
    partial void OnIdChanged();
    partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
    partial void OnNameChanged();
    partial void OnTypeIdChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnTypeIdChanged();
    #endregion

        public testuser()
        {
            this._testtype = default(EntityRef<testtype>);
            OnCreated();
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Id != value))
                {
                    this.OnIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Id = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                    this.OnIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Name != value))
                {
                    this.OnNameChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Name = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Name");
                    this.OnNameChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_TypeId", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> TypeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._TypeId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._TypeId != value))
                {
                    if (this._testtype.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                    {
                        throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                    }
                    this.OnTypeIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._TypeId = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("TypeId");
                    this.OnTypeIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="testtype_testuser", Storage="_testtype", ThisKey="TypeId", OtherKey="Id", IsForeignKey=true)]
        public testtype testtype
        {
            get
            {
                return this._testtype.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                testtype previousValue = this._testtype.Entity;
                if (((previousValue != value) 
                            || (this._testtype.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                {
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    if ((previousValue != null))
                    {
                        this._testtype.Entity = null;
                        previousValue.testusers.Remove(this);
                    }
                    this._testtype.Entity = value;
                    if ((value != null))
                    {
                        value.testusers.Add(this);
                        this._TypeId = value.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._TypeId = default(Nullable<int>);
                    }
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("testtype");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class FetchPropertiesResult
    {

        private int _ProdPropId;

        private string _propertyName;

        private string _UnitName;

        private string _propertyCatName;

        private string _sqlType;

        private string _stringVal;

        private string _shortStringVal;

        private System.Nullable<int> _measurmentVal;

        private System.Nullable<bool> _boolVal;

        private int _OrderId;

        public FetchPropertiesResult()
        {
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ProdPropId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
        public int ProdPropId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ProdPropId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._ProdPropId != value))
                {
                    this._ProdPropId = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_propertyName", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string propertyName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._propertyName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._propertyName != value))
                {
                    this._propertyName = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_UnitName", DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
        public string UnitName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._UnitName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._UnitName != value))
                {
                    this._UnitName = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_propertyCatName", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string propertyCatName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._propertyCatName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._propertyCatName != value))
                {
                    this._propertyCatName = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_sqlType", DbType="NVarChar(20) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string sqlType
        {
            get
            {
                return this._sqlType;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._sqlType != value))
                {
                    this._sqlType = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_stringVal", DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")]
        public string stringVal
        {
            get
            {
                return this._stringVal;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._stringVal != value))
                {
                    this._stringVal = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_shortStringVal", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
        public string shortStringVal
        {
            get
            {
                return this._shortStringVal;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._shortStringVal != value))
                {
                    this._shortStringVal = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_measurmentVal", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> measurmentVal
        {
            get
            {
                return this._measurmentVal;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._measurmentVal != value))
                {
                    this._measurmentVal = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_boolVal", DbType="Bit")]
        public System.Nullable<bool> boolVal
        {
            get
            {
                return this._boolVal;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._boolVal != value))
                {
                    this._boolVal = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_OrderId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
        public int OrderId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._OrderId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._OrderId != value))
                {
                    this._OrderId = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'i think vs 2012 has bug!', Nope your DAL code might have one. Can you post that as well ?

Comment: @DamienJoe tnx  dear, but what's wrong?

Comment: @GertArnold yes :) he know by this. EnableUpdate="true" and work for name but not work for...

Comment: for... the child object? You have to tell the grid how to update `testtype.Name`.